# Reading data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

In my database table, I have a lot of questions ,each having a category . Say, there are 100 questions and some number of categories which I don't know . I want to know the number and the names of the categories.
Please tell the way to do it in php.

Comment: Ask yourself: is it even possible for anyone to answer your question without having mind reading powers? Please provide more information and show what have you tried, otherwise won't be surprised if this question will be downvoted and closed very quickly.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the PHP tutorial you're learning from doesn't show how to do MySQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT category_name FROM your_table GROUP BY category_name");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result); // no of categories 
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo $row[0]; // printing category name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect( /*  info  */) or die ("MySQL error");
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `category`)");
echo $result;
?>
```

That is assuming categories are all in a single column.